# Why am I Getting this Error in Swiftmailer: unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to use swiftmailer for the first time. I am getting a number of errors when I use the code below, including this one: "unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR." 
Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here?

```
require_once('/home/name/php/lib/swift_required.php');

$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/exim -bs');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
->setSubject('Inquiry');
->setFrom(array('email@example.com' => 'Inquiry'))
->setTo(array('email@example.com' => 'John Doe'))
->setBody('Test inquiry message');

$numSent = $mailer->send($message);

printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had `;` after `Swift_Message::newInstance()` causing parse error in PHP

Answer (score 1):

You have one semicolon too many...:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance(); <-- remove this semicolon
->setSubject('Inquiry');
->setFrom(array('email@example.com' => 'Inquiry'))
->setTo(array('email@example.com' => 'John Doe'))
->setBody('Test inquiry message');
```